# Lock scale on multiple axis ssrs

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a chart in SSRS (reporting services) that is using both the primary and secondary y axis to plot 4 different years of data.  I am also using a series group for multiple values stacked.  The problem that I am having is that the 2 axis's are not using the same scale so the numbers look like they don't match the table that is also on this report.  How can I lock the 2 axis's so they use the same scale. I would like to still use auto axis if possible so I don't have to calculate the max and min myself.  [image: Designer View![][1]]
[image: Output view]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click an axis and select "Axis Properties". In the Axis Options tab you can set the minimum and maximum values of the axis, you want these values to be set to a value (Not Auto) and for both graphs to hold the same values. This is to say for example that a minimum = 0 and maximum = 10 that the graph will start at 0 and end at 10 , if you have a value of 11 it will just hit the top of the graph. You will also want to set the interval. An interval of 1 would make the axis read 0,1,2,3 etc, an interval of 2 would make it go 0,2,4,6 etc and again you want the same value set on both graphs.

[image: Vertical Axis Properties]

Comment: Thanks.  Actually I was looking for the properties of the secondary axis but I couldn't find it because I had hidden the secondary axis.  I was hoping there was some way that I could do it automagically but it seems I will have to write a complex expression to do the scale based on the highest value in the table.